# Finding intraday "run-ups" in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

How to find all, non-overlapping, 1% run-ups during each calendar day?

```
                            Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  barCount  
date                                                                       
2021-11-15 09:00:00+01:00  308.0  308.0  304.6  305.1  31477.0       122   
2021-11-15 09:05:00+01:00  305.2  306.1  304.3  304.6  20433.0        92   
2021-11-15 09:10:00+01:00  304.5  304.9  304.3  304.9  14094.0        81   
2021-11-15 09:15:00+01:00  305.1  305.1  304.2  304.3  14412.0        79   
2021-11-15 09:20:00+01:00  304.3  304.9  303.9  304.8  28365.0        99
```

I would look at df.Low and see if there is a value of df.High that is 1% higher on the same day.

Let's say at 12:00 df.High is 307.7 which would be a 1% gain from df.Low[0] - that would qualify as a "run-up".

However since df.Low went down to 303.9 at 09:20 there could be a 1% match sooner than the one at 12:00 if df.High reached 307 before that time. (1% gain from 303.9)

The code should initially find the FIRST 1% gain of the day.

Once the first run-up of the day is completed, the "search" would start over and a new minimum of df.Low would be recalculated from that point on, to compare against a new future run-up of 1%.

I could create new bool columns df.Run_start, df.Run_end, df.Run_duration to be set accordingly.
I don't mind using forward/look-ahead data.

I can create a daily Min column:

```
 df['Min'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['Low'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().min())
```

Finding the first run-up of the day is quite straight-forward, but after the first run-up is completed, I'm struggling with resetting my df.Min to find the next 1% gain AFTER the previous run is completed.

At the beginning of each calendar day, the "search" resets.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can two "run-ups" use the same timestamped value? For example, assuming timestamps t0, t1, t2 are ordered sequentially, i.e., t0>t1>t2, suppose that the time pair (t0,t2) qualifies as a run-up, can (t1,t2) be another run-up?

Comment: The time periods in your example would be overlapping.

If the first run is t0 to t2, the next run could start at the earliest on t3.

Comment: Further,  1% gains on the same bar (same 5 min time period) should not be considered as it's not known if High or Low came first during that period.